# Find frequency of each array element

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this hackerank thing to do. N must be <= 1 000 000. Each element must be between 20 and 50, but I don't know how to make that, havent done much competitive programming.
The user enters N numbers. The program finds the frequencies of each element and print them descending.
I tried doing a while loop (see in main), but that didnt work. Please help.

> Input format:
>
> 9
>
> 42 42 34 26 42 35 34 47 47
>
> Output:
>
> 42 3
>
> 34 2
>
> 47 2
>
> 26 1
>
> 35 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct ele
{
    int count, index, val;
};


bool mycomp(struct ele a, struct ele b) {
    return (a.val < b.val);
}

bool mycomp2(struct ele a, struct ele b) {
     if (a.count != b.count) return (a.count < b.count);
    else return a.index > b.index;
}

void sortByFrequency(int arr[], int n)
{
    struct ele element[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        element[i].index = i;
        element[i].count = 0;
        element[i].val = arr[i];

    }

    stable_sort(element, element + n, mycomp);

    element[0].count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (element[i].val == element[i - 1].val)
        {
            element[i].count += element[i - 1].count + 1;

            element[i - 1].count = -1;

            element[i].index = element[i - 1].index;
        }

        else element[i].count = 1;
   }
   stable_sort(element, element + n, mycomp2);
   for (int i = n - 1, index = 0; i >= 0; i--)
       if (element[i].count != -1)
           for (int j = 0; j < element[i].count; j++)
               arr[index++] = element[i].val;
   }

int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[n];
    int* seen = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        while(arr[i] < 20 || arr[i] > 50) 
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    sortByFrequency(arr, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (seen[i] == 0) {
            int count = 0;
           for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                    count += 1;
                    seen[j] = 1;
                }
            cout << arr[i] << " " << count << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _but that didnt work._ What didn't work? Unexpected output? Time length exceeded? The output doesn't look that bad. Instead of sorting, you could just count the occurrences. To count possible values in a range [20, 50], an array with size 50 - 20 + 1 would be sufficient.

Comment: I didn't pass all test cases. They are all hidden.

Comment: Not very helpful. How should you know what should be improved? That's annoying...

Comment: You can use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Comment: When you don't know the test cases you must invent your own. Here's a case to check:`n` = 1,000,000.  `struct ele element[n];` is a variable length array. One of the reasons they've not been included in Standard C++ is they are very easy way to cause a Stack Overflow. `ele` could be 24 bytes long. You could have an `n` of 1,000,000. That's 24,000,000 bytes of Automatic storage (typically stack). It is unusual to get more than 10 MB of Automatic storage. Fortunately @Scheff has already pointed out that you don't need `n` frequencies.

Comment: @VishnuDasu has a great idea. If you want to do competitive programming, you need to develop programs quickly. The best way to do that is be familiar with the libraries at your disposal. Several reasons for this, but the big two are 1) Code you don't have to write saves you time. 2) A successful library has been tested and proven by thousands or millions of programmers. You probably won't have to debug it. All you need to do is know what the library provides and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I consider competitive programming helpful to improve programming skills. (At least, not the programming skills for daily business.) However, I was tempted and couldn't resist. (It's Monday morning and, may be, a nice warm-up for the week.)

Compiling the ideas of comments I got this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  // input and count frequency
  int n; std::cin >> n;
  assert(n >= 0 && n < 1000000);
  const int valueMin = 20, valueMax = 50;
  int freq[valueMax - valueMin + 1] {};
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int value; std::cin >> value;
    ++freq[value - valueMin];
  }
  // sort frequency
  std::set<std::pair<int, int>, bool(*)(const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)>
    freqSorted([](const std::pair<int, int> &pair1, const std::pair<int, int> &pair2) {
      if (pair1.first != pair2.first) return pair1.first > pair2.first;
      return pair1.second < pair2.second;
    });
  for (int i = valueMin; i <= valueMax; ++i) {
    if (const int freqI = freq[i - valueMin]) {
      freqSorted.insert(std::make_pair(freqI, i));
    }
  }
  // output
  for (std::pair<int, int> entry : freqSorted) {
    std::cout << entry.second << ' ' << entry.first << '\n';
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. I use

   ```
   const int valueMin = 20, valueMax = 50;
   int freq[valueMax - valueMin + 1] {};
   ```

   to store number of occurrences with a minimal memory footprint. (The explicit restriction of range for input values encouraged me.)
2. user4581301 made me sensitive concerning memory consumption. (Before reading it, I hadn't realized that storage of input values is actually not necessary.)
3. Using a `std::map` (like recommended by Vishnu Dasu) was my first idea too. When testing I wondered about missing results until I realized that a `map` with number of occurrence as key will store only one of multiple values with same frequency.
   Hence, I changed it into a `std::set` with both values as key.

Output:

```
42 3
34 2
47 2
26 1
35 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8996c48771d9dfc6)</kbd>

Comment: Great, the only thing I didnt mention is that if there are 2 elements with the same frequency, you print the smaller number first.

Comment: @TedA. If this is against required then the lambda in set had to be adjusted... It's exactly like in your question. ;-)

Comment: it is required so all test cases can be passed. Yours passes 5/6

Comment: @TedA. Is it required to print smaller number first for two equal frequencies? This is exactly what I did. Have a look at the lambda. First is frequency -> compared with `>`. Second is value -> compared with `<`.

Comment: It is. There isnt anything i havent mentioned. I checked it. It just says "Wrong Answer" on the last test case.

Comment: @TedA. Likely there is some sneaky case tripping things up. You have two options here: Find a different solution that doesn't trip over this case or expand your test cases to discover this case. The second option is probably more educational. The first case may be faster, but riskier. After all, if you don't know what the error case is, how can you be sure any alternative solution resolves it successfully without writing and trying it? Three or four tries and failures in and you may well have been better off hunting and killing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I wonder, how many lines of code can be written for simple tasks. Anyway.

There is a more or less standard approach for counting something in general or in a container.

We can use an associative container like a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. And here we associate a "key", in this case the number, to a count, with a value, in this case the count of the specific number.

And luckily the maps have a very nice index operator[]. This will look for the given key and, if found, return a reference to the value. If not found, then it will create a new entry with the key and return a reference to the new entry. So, in both cases, we will get a reference to the value used for counting. And then we can simply write:

```
std::unordered_map<int,unsigned int> counter{};
counter[value]++;
```

And that looks really intuitive.

After this operation, you have already the frequency table. Either sorted by the key (the value), by using a `std::map` or unsorted, but faster accessible with a `std::unordered_map`. Since the `std::unordered_map` uses hashes, it is usually very fast.

Now you want to sort according to the frequency/count. Unfortunately this is not possible with maps.

Therefore we need to use a second container, like a `std::vector` which we then can sort unsing `std::sort` for any given predicate, or, we can copy the values into a container, like a `std::multiset` that implicitely orders its elements.

This is, what we will do and what will result in some very compact code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <set>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<int, unsigned int>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Sorter = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {

    // Read number of elements to check
    if (int numberOfElements{}; std::cin >> numberOfElements) {

        // Read and count
        Counter counter{};
        for (int i{}, value{}; (i < numberOfElements) && (std::cin >> value); counter[value]++, ++i);

        // Sort
        Sorter sorter(counter.begin(), counter.end());

        // Show result
        for (const auto& [value, count] : sorter) std::cout << value << ' ' << count << '\n';
    }
}
```